# Not able to update cell value using setCellValue api in java

Tags: java, excel

I want to update Specific cell value using java excel API, i am using bellow code snippet but cell value is not updating.

```
public void update_excel() throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream excel_file = new FileInputStream(Test.excelfilepath);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excel_file);
        XSSFSheet excel_sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        XSSFCell cell1=excel_sheet.createRow(1).createCell(2);
        cell1.setCellValue("abc");
        excel_file.close();
    }
```

Comment: for the value to be saved you need to call `workbook.write(excel_file);` and `workbook.close();`

Comment: i made a mistake i see. you need an outpustream like this: `OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)`

Comment: Not able to do that because excel_file is Input stream and write api requires output stream.

Comment: thats why i wrote a second comment

Comment: Thanks. it is working

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to update a cell value.

```
FileInputStream excel_file= new FileInputStream(new File("Test.excelfilepath)); //Read the spreadsheet that needs to be updated
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(excel_file); //Access the workbook
HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(1); //Access the worksheet, so that we can update / modify it.
Cell cell = null; // declare a Cell object
cell = worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);   // Access the second cell in second row to update the value
cell.setCellValue("OverRide Value");  // Get current cell value value and overwrite the value
excel_file.close(); //Close the InputStream
FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.excelfilepath));  //Open FileOutputStream to write updates
wb.write(output_file); //write changes
output_file.close();  //close the stream
```